# TypeScriptの連想配列操作

Tags: javascript, typescript

**TypeScriptの連想配列の操作について**

```
data: [ {dataId:1,fruitId:1,name:'りんご',text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},
        {dataId:2,fruitId:1,name:'りんご',text1:'3文字',text2:'赤い'},
        {dataId:1,fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},
        {dataId:2,fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',text1:'4文字',text2:'オレンジ色'},
        {dataId:1,fruitId:3,name:'なす',text1:'2文字',text2:'野菜'},
      ]
```

上記のような連想配列があるのですが、

```
type Fruit = FruitIndex & {
  fruitDetails: FruitDetail[];
}
type FruitIndex ={
  fruitId:number;
  name:string;
  count:number;
}
type FruitDetail ={
  text1:string;
  text2:string;
}


const method = (): [number, Fruit[]] => {
let total = 0;
//////////////下記を修正したい///////////////////////
const tmpFruits:Fruit[] = data.map((fruit)=>{
  const fruitDetails:FruitDetail[]=[
    {
      text1:fruit.text1,
      text2:fruit.text2,
    }
  ];
  const count = 1;
  total = count;

  return {
    fruitId:fruit.fruitId,
    name:fruit.name,
    fruitDetails,
    count,
  };
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
});
  return [total,tmpFruits];
}
const [total,tmpFruits] = method();
```

tmpFruitsの結果は

```
{fruitId:1,name:'りんご',count:1,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'}]},
{fruitId:1,name:'りんご',count:1,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'3文字',text2:'赤い'}]},
{fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',count:1,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'}]},
{fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',count:1,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'4文字',text2:'オレンジ色'}]},
{fruitId:3,name:'なす',count:1,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'2文字',text2:'野菜'}]},
```

となります。

```
totalは1
```

となります。

tmpFruitsに求める結果としては

```
{fruitId:1,name:'りんご',count:2,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},{text1:'3文字',text2:'赤い'}]},
{fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',count:2,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},{text1:'4文字',text2:'オレンジ色'}]},
{fruitId:3,name:'なす',count:1,fruitlDetails:{text1:'2文字',text2:'野菜'}},
```

です。

```
totalは5
```

です。

また fruitIdは一意・下記を修正したい///の範囲内のみ変更したいです。

かなり初歩的なのですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

データ構造がちょっと複雑なので`map`や`reduce`を使わず、forEachを使ってみました。

```
interface FruitDetail {
  text1: string;
  text2: string;
}

interface FruitIndex {
  fruitId: number;
  name: string;
  count: number;
}

interface InputData extends FruitDetail {
  dataId: number;
  fruitId: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Fruit extends FruitIndex {
  fruitDetails: FruitDetail[];
}

const data: InputData[] = [
  { dataId: 1, fruitId: 1, name: "りんご", text1: "ひらがな", text2: "果物" },
  { dataId: 2, fruitId: 1, name: "りんご", text1: "3文字", text2: "赤い" },
  { dataId: 1, fruitId: 2, name: "オレンジ", text1: "ひらがな", text2: "果物" },
  {
    dataId: 2,
    fruitId: 2,
    name: "オレンジ",
    text1: "4文字",
    text2: "オレンジ色",
  },
  { dataId: 1, fruitId: 3, name: "なす", text1: "2文字", text2: "野菜" },
];

const method = (): [number, Fruit[]] => {
  // keyをユニークなものを利用すると処理しやすい
  const fruits: { [fruitId: number]: Fruit } = {};
  data.forEach((item) => {
    if (fruits[item.fruitId]) {
      // objectのvalueがない場合
      fruits[item.fruitId].count += 1;
      fruits[item.fruitId].fruitDetails.push({
        text1: item.text1,
        text2: item.text2,
      });
    } else {
      // すでにobjectのvalueが存在する場合
      fruits[item.fruitId] = {
        fruitId: item.fruitId,
        name: item.name,
        count: 1,
        fruitDetails: [
          {
            text1: item.text1,
            text2: item.text2,
          },
        ],
      };
    }
  });
  // totalはdataの長さで良さそう
  // objectのvalueをObject.valuesで取り出すとFruitの配列になる
  return [data.length, Object.values(fruits)];
};

const [total, tmpFruits] = method();
```

※ 余談ですが、型定義の際、`type`よりも`interface`を使うとビルド時のキャッシュが効きます。規模が大きくなったときに差が出ます。

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#preferring-interfaces-over-intersections

Answer (score 0):

動作確認例をjsbinに載せました。
https://jsbin.com/fajuyabacu/edit?html,js,console

JSですが、以前、group化するための関数を書いたことがあります。

https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/blob/v9.1.0/source/array/_group.js
簡単なコードだと思います。それを使うと、こんな感じで書くことができました。

```
const data = [ {dataId:1,fruitId:1,name:'りんご',text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},
    {dataId:2,fruitId:1,name:'りんご',text1:'3文字',text2:'赤い'},
    {dataId:1,fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},
    {dataId:2,fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',text1:'4文字',text2:'オレンジ色'},
    {dataId:1,fruitId:3,name:'なす',text1:'2文字',text2:'野菜'},
  ]

const result = [
{fruitId:1,name:'りんご',count:2,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},{text1:'3文字',text2:'赤い'}]},
{fruitId:2,name:'オレンジ',count:2,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'ひらがな',text2:'果物'},{text1:'4文字',text2:'オレンジ色'}]},
{fruitId:3,name:'なす',count:1,fruitlDetails:[{text1:'2文字',text2:'野菜'}]},
];

const group = parts.array.group(data, item => item.name);
const group2 = group.map(item => (
  {
    fruitId:   item[0].fruitId,
    name: item[0].name,
    count: item.length,
    fruitlDetails: item.map(item => ({text1: item.text1, text2: item.text2})),

  }
))

console.log(
  group2,
  parts.equalDeep(group2, result)
);
```

なすのfruitlDetailsだけ質問が配列になっていなかったので、そこは長さ1の配列にしました。